# Retrieving Record types for a given picklist

Tags: picklist, metadata-api, record-type

On a given object `s_object__c` i have a very long picklist with many values [`picklist_val_1`,`picklist_val_2`,`picklist_val_3`...etc].
These values are availible to some record types and not others (`record_type_1`, `record_type_2`.. etc).

I can find how to get a list of each picklist value available per record type, but I cannot find out how to get the reverse.

Is there somewhere on the metadata api I can get a list/table/csv along the lines of...

> | _picklist_val_  | record_types | 
>   |-----------------|---------------------------------------|
>  |
>   picklist_val_1  | record_type_10, record_type_16  |
>  |
>   picklist_val_2  | record_type_10, record_type_99  |
>  |
>   picklist_val_3  | record_type_12, record_type_16  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is currently possible with a single Metadata API call (as at Spring '17).

Instead you will need to get all the [RecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm) records and the associated `picklistValues`. Then build up a Map from each [PicklistValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalpicklistvalue.htm#picklistvalue) back to the RecordTypes it is used on.